# How to use jeasyui with C#server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, jquery

i have been developing a web application using JqueryeasyUi([jeasyui CRUD with PHP](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud2.php)). iam trynig to do CRUD processes. But jeasyui samples are PHP. if you look link , every things are php. i want to make it :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#dg').edatagrid({
            url: 'get_users.php',
            saveUrl: 'save_user.php',
            updateUrl: 'update_user.php',
            destroyUrl: 'destroy_user.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

TO C#

```
$(function () {
    $('#dg').edatagrid({
        url: 'VisitorsAdvertisements.aspx/FillGv',
        saveUrl: 'save_user.aspx/Save',
        updateUrl: 'gdgdf.aspx/fsfsd',
        destroyUrl: 'fsfsfds.aspx/fsfd'
    });
```

My Fill method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public   DataTable FillGv()
    {
            int TagID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["TagID"]);
            return new MyVisitorAdvertisement().ListVisitorAdvertisementReviewByTID(TagID);
    }
```

How can i do that? how can fill table using C# using jeasyui(Please dont give advertisement another jquery library or what else ONLY jeasyui) or Save?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the basic idea. You just need to return data that the grid can use which is JSON. This method converts a datatable to Json which you can return

```
public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
{
  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  List<Dictionary> rows = new List<Dictionary>();
  Dictionary row = null;

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
   row = new Dictionary();
   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
     row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
   }
   rows.Add(row);
 }
 return serializer.Serialize(rows);
 }
```

Your fill method would just return a string.